# Hibernate saveOrUpdate-method creates new entry/row instead of updating the existing one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, one-to-one

I'm currently making a website to provide product management for a registered user. It uses spring + hibernate + mysql + jsp. Hibernates saveOrUpdate-method creates always a new entry/row to the database for the ProductDetail-entity instead of updating the already existing one. I have done the mapping according to the tutorials out there and I cannot understand what makes it to create a new row, because I have established the relationships to the Product- and ProductDetail-entity (OneToOne) in the Controller layer before the use. Someone save me from this struggle, I have been stuck here for more than 3 months... Below I will provide pictures of the Entities, Controller and DAO.

Product Entity (nvm commented annotations)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @NotNull(message = "Product name is required")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "is required")
    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;

    @DecimalMin(value = "0.01", inclusive = true, message = "Price must be a minimum of 0.01$")
    @Digits(integer = 6, fraction = 2, message = "Price out of bounds, limit <6 digits>.<2 digits>")
    @Column(name = "price")
    private float price;

    @NotNull(message = "Quantity is required")
    @Min(value = 1, message = "Must be greater than zero")
    @Column(name = "qty")
    private Integer quantity;

    @NotNull(message = "Email is required")
    @Email(message = "Provide a valid email address")
    @Pattern(regexp = ".+@.+\\..+", message = "Provide a valid email address")
    @Column(name = "added_by")
    private String addedBy;

    @Column(name = "creation_datetime")
    private Date createDateTime;


    //@Version
    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    private Date updateDateTime;


    //@Valid
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private ProductDetail productDetail;

    @Column(name = "value_in_stock")
    private float valueInStock;

    public Product() {
        this.createDateTime = new Date();
        this.updateDateTime = this.createDateTime;
    }

    public Product(String productName, float price, Integer quantity, String addedBy) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.addedBy = addedBy;
        this.valueInStock = this.price * this.quantity;
    }

        public void setProductDetail(ProductDetail productDetail) {
        if (productDetail == null) {
            if (this.productDetail != null) {
                this.productDetail.setProduct(null);
            }
        } else {
            productDetail.setProduct(this);
        }
        this.productDetail = productDetail;
    }
// getters and setters
```

ProductDetail entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_detail")
public class ProductDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @NotNull(message = "A descriptionis required")
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @NotNull(message = "Category is required")
    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;

    @DecimalMin(value = "0.001", inclusive = true, message = "Must a minimum of 0.001g")
    @Digits(integer = 7, fraction = 2, message = "Weight out of bounds, limit <7 digits>.<2 digits>")
    @Column(name = "weight_g")
    private float weight;

    @NotNull(message = "Manufacturer is required")
    @Column(name = "manufacturer")
    private String manufacturer;

    @NotNull(message = "Provide a country")
    @Column(name = "made_in_country")
    private String countryMadeIn;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    public ProductDetail() {

    }

    public ProductDetail(String description, String category, String manufacturer, String madeIn) {
        this.description = description;
        this.category = category;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.countryMadeIn = madeIn;
    }
// Getters and setters...
```

ProductController

Method to fetch form for adding a new product (GET request)

```
@GetMapping("/add")
public String getAddForm(Model model) {

        // create model attribute to bind all form data
        Product product = new Product();
        ProductDetail productDetail = new ProductDetail();

        // associating product and product details
        product.setProductDetail(productDetail);
        product.getProductDetail());

        model.addAttribute("categoryMap", categoryOptions);
        model.addAttribute("countryMap", countryOptions);
        model.addAttribute("product", product);

        return "product-form";
    }
```

Method to fetch product by id from productService (delegates data fetching to productDAO) (GET request)

```
@GetMapping("/updateProduct")
public String getUpdateForm(@RequestParam("productId") int productId, Model model) {

        // get product from db
        Product product = productService.getProduct(productId);
        product.getProductDetail());

        // set product as a model to pre-populate the form
        model.addAttribute("categoryMap", categoryOptions);
        model.addAttribute("countryMap", countryOptions);
        model.addAttribute("product", product);

        return "product-form";
    }
```

Method to process saving/updating the Product and its ProductDetail (POST request)

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String saveOrUpdate(@Valid @ModelAttribute("product") Product product, BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model) {

        // if result set has errors, return to product form with errors
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("categoryMap", categoryOptions);
            model.addAttribute("countryMap", countryOptions);
            return "product-form";
        } else {

            // calculate value in stock to product before saving
            product.setValueInStock();

            productService.saveProduct(product);

            return "redirect:/";
        }

    }
```

ProductDAOImpl

Method to saveOrUpdate given product

```
@Override
    public void saveProduct(Product product) {

        // get current hibernate session
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        // save or update given product
        session.saveOrUpdate(product);
    }
```

Method to fetch product by its id

```
@Override
    public Product getProduct(int id) {

        // get current hibernate session
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query<Product> query = 
                session.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p "
                        + "JOIN FETCH p.productDetail "
                        + "WHERE p.id=:productId",
                        Product.class);

        // set parameters in query
        query.setParameter("productId", id);

        // execute and get product
        Product product = query.getSingleResult();

        return product;
    }
```

And finally here is the JSP form itself

```
<form:form action="save" modelAttribute="product" method="POST">

                <!-- associate data with product id -->
                <form:hidden path="id" />

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="nameInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Product name *:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:input path="productName" cssClass="form-control" id="nameInput" placeholder="Enter name" />
                        <form:errors path="productName" cssClass="errors" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="priceInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Price($) *:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:input path="price" cssClass="form-control" id="priceInput" placeholder="Enter price" />
                        <form:errors path="price" cssClass="errors" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="quantityInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Quantity *:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:input path="quantity" cssClass="form-control" id="quantityInput" placeholder="Enter qty" />
                        <form:errors path="quantity" cssClass="errors" />
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="emailInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Added by(email) *:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:input path="addedBy" cssClass="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="example.address@email.com" />
                        <form:errors path="addedBy" cssClass="errors"  />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="separator" > </div>


                <h5 id="header" >Product Details (Can be updated later)</h5>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="categoryInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Category *:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <form:select path="productDetail.category" id="categoryInput" cssClass="form-control">
                            <form:option value="" label="Select Product Category" />
                            <form:options items="${categoryMap}"/>
                        </form:select>
                        <form:errors path="productDetail.category" cssClass="errors"  />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="manufacturerInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Manufacturer *:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:input path="productDetail.manufacturer" cssClass="form-control" id="manufacturerInput" placeholder="Enter manufacturer" />
                        <form:errors path="productDetail.manufacturer" cssClass="errors" />
                    </div>

                    <label for="madeInInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Country *:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <form:select path="productDetail.countryMadeIn" id="madeInInput" cssClass="form-control">
                            <form:option value="" label="Country manufactured in" />
                            <form:options items="${countryMap}"/>
                        </form:select>
                        <form:errors path="productDetail.countryMadeIn" cssClass="errors"  />
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="descriptionInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Description *:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:textarea path="productDetail.description" cssClass="form-control" id="descriptionInput" placeholder="Short description of product..." />
                        <form:errors path="productDetail.description" cssClass="errors"  />
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="weightInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Weight(g):</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <form:input path="productDetail.weight" cssClass="form-control" id="weightInput" placeholder="Enter weight" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />

</form:form>
```

So the user should be able to add and update a product. At the moment this just adds and when the user wants to update the product, it just creates a new ProductDetail-entity instead of updating the ProductDetail on the fetched Product-entity.

Comment: Have you verified that the entity instance has an id (and that it is correct) when passed to the update method?

Comment: Yes with the good old sysout printline. Actually when processes it in the POST req, it seems to have all the right info, but the id of ProductDetail seems to be 0 for some reason... While it fetches it from the the DAO the id is set according the DB. Could it be that the spring form messes this id up for me?

Comment: You should add a hidden key to productionDetail.id

Comment: @Kartik thank you it works now that i added this hidden key! Huge thanks fellow.

Comment: @SaitamaCoding I can add an answer an official answer, and you can upvote it.

Comment: @Kartik Yes go ahead!

Comment: @SaitamaCoding Done https://stackoverflow.com/a/55990351/300327

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a hidden key for `productDetail.id` or else it considers product detail object to be a transient one and saves it as a new object instead of updating it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using primitive data type `int`. Update it to `Integer` and it should work fine.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
```

Update it to,

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
```

NOTE : Regenerate the corresponding getter/setters for this field.

Comment: Thank you! I already got it working from a solution provided in the comments.

Comment: Your solution works, but may I know the reason why we cannot have identity fields as int?